# How to check if an element contains a certain string in puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I'm trying to find out if an element `#view_container > div > div > div.pwWryf.bxPAYd > div > div.WEQkZc > div > form > content > section > div > content > div.ck6P8 > div > div` contains a certain set of characters `(•••)`. I'm pretty new to coding so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('https://example.org/');

    const stringIsIncluded = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const string = '...';
      const selector = 'p > a[href]';
      return document.querySelector(selector).innerText.includes(string);
    });

    console.log(stringIsIncluded);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

You can use `.textContent` instead of `.innerText` if you need element's raw text with all the white spaces not normalized to be checked.

Comment: how would I turn this into an if else function?

If the url contains a certain string: do this

else: go to next line of code

Comment: You can transfer the URL from ` page.evaluate()` into the puppeteer context and then use if - else there.

Comment: could you show an example? Sorry, I am new to coding.

Comment: What is the URL in your case? Is this a href of a link?

Comment: I'm looking to only have it read a certain part of a URL. In this case: ```https://kith.com/throttle/queue?``` but after the '?' anything can come after it so I only want it to read up to the question mark

Comment: You can try: `const url = page.evaluate(() => { /* return the URL */ }); if(url.startsWith('https://kith.com/throttle/queue?')) {} else {}`

Comment: what would go where u have { /* return the url  */ }    ?

Comment: I do not understand what URL exactly you mean. Is this a href of a link in the page? Or is this a request URL? A page URL? An image src? I cannot tell you what would go in { /* return the url */ } for now till I understand.

Comment: basically kith.com/throttle/queue is the URL of when ur in line on the website

Comment: But how do you get this URL? What is the source?

Comment: after carting, and clicking checkout, if there is enough people on the site it puts you into the queue.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not understand. Maybe it would be better if you ask a separate question with detailed explanation.

Comment: so on kith.com, I cart the product, click checkout, then it puts you into line where you wait to be redirected to the checkout page.

Comment: If this is the same question, let's continue there: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725357/if-url-contains-function-in-puppeteer

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [$$eval](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevalselector-pagefunction-args)

```
page.$$eval('#view_container > div', (elements) =>
  elements.some((el) => el.textContent.includes('some text'))
);
```