# if URL contains function in puppeteer

Tags: web-scraping, puppeteer

So I am trying to have my code do something if the URL contains this: https://kith.com/throttle/queue?

After the '?' there can be anything, so I only want it to identify 'https://kith.com/throttle/queue?'

I am using puppeteer and want it to work like this:
If the URL contains 'https://kith.com/throttle/queue?' then wait until it passes the queue `(page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2' })` would work for waiting until it's through the queue

Else (If the URL doesn't contain that): do nothing and go to the next line of code

Comment: Can you give an example of "can be anything"? Aren't you mean URL parameters and not functions?

Comment: Maybe `url.starsWith('https://kith.com/throttle/queue?')` suffices?

Comment: could you show an example? How would I implement that into a ty loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to understand how do you get this URL, but if this is a URL of a current page, you can try this:

```js
const url = await page.evaluate(() => location.href);

if(url.startsWith('https://kith.com/throttle/queue?')) {
  // Wait for navigation.
} else {
  // Do nothing.
}
```

Comment: wow, that worked! Thank you! The queue is not up tho so I am not able to test it, but it didn't break at that point(it was before). Thanks!

Comment: how would I do this now with the ending of a URL? url.endsWith?

Comment: Yes. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

Comment: that talks about strings not URLs

Comment: In you case, the URL is in the string type. `location.href` returns URL as a string.

Comment: This worked! Thanks! One last thing: can you take a look at this please?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736740/how-can-i-make-a-monitoring-function-to-wait-for-an-html-element-in-puppeteer