# How can I make a monitoring function to wait for an html element in puppeteer

Tags: puppeteer

How can I make a function that waits until a certain CSS selector loads in puppeteer?

I want to refresh the page over and over until the '.product-form__add-to-cart' is present, then I want it to continue on with the code.

Answer (score 1):

The corresponding puppeteer method is [`page.waitForSelector`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-pagewaitforselectorselector-options).

Example:

```js
await page.waitForSelector('.product-form__add-to-cart')
```

But if you need to reload the page to get the desired element (maybe because the site you are visiting can look different between visits) than you can just check if the element is present in the DOM after the page is rendered and if not: then you can try to [`page.reload`](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v5.0.0&show=api-pagereloadoptions) it.

```js
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
const selectorExists = await page.$('.product-form__add-to-cart')

if (selectorExists !== null) {
  // do something with the element
} else {
  await page.reload({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
}
```

You can do it in a loop as well, where you [`break`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/break) if the selector appears, but be careful: if it never shows up you will end up in an endless loop! Set a maximum number of tries.

---

### Edit

If you are sure about running it in a loop until the selector appears: then you can try with a while loop:

```js
await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
let selectorExists = await page.$('.product-form__add-to-cart')

while (selectorExists === null) {
  await page.reload({ waitUntil: 'domcontentloaded' })
  selectorExists = await page.$('.product-form__add-to-cart')
}
// if condition meets the script will go on
```

As I said earlier: you can end up with an endless loop like this, so be careful.

Comment: I want it to go in an endless loop until it appears actually. What can I do to have it just go to the line of code after the loop if the selector does appear? Like this:

If : Selector Appears then go to next line of code
Else : Reload page

Comment: See my edited answer: it can be done with a [while loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/while). As I said: be careful.