# Puppeteer refresh until selector value change?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, puppeteer

I'm looking to have puppeteer refresh until a class I want to sign up for opens up. I plan on having the page refresh every 30 seconds or so until the selector to select the class opens. I've gone far enough to sign-in and get to the final page, but I can't wrap my head around the repeating part. A normal JS function brings an error.

```
page2.waitForNavigation()
await page2.waitFor(4000)
await page2.select('select[name="country"]', "USA")
await page2.click('#searchZip');

function findClass() {  
page2.waitForNavigation()
await page2.waitFor(4000)
await page2.click('#showAvailableOnly');
await page2.evaluate(() => {
let el = document.querySelector(".dataTables_empty")
result = el.innerText
if (result = "No matching records found") {
    console.log("Could not find any open test centers. Waiting 60 seconds to refresh.");
```

> I want to have puppeteer wait 30 seconds here, and then run the code after `findClass()` again, until the `result` changes.

```
} else {
    console.log("Found opening!");
}})     
}
```

I would appreciate any help, as I am pretty new to puppeteer, or nodejs in general. Thank you so much!

Comment: does this answer address your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62736740/how-can-i-make-a-monitoring-function-to-wait-for-an-html-element-in-puppeteer/62738285#62738285 (especially the one with a while loop)

Comment: That worked perfectly David. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in pupeteer there is a function you may use

```
await page.waitFor(30000);
```

or you can use as a second solution

```
    function delay(time) {
   return new Promise(function(resolve) { 
       setTimeout(resolve, time)
   });
}
```

then call it

```
await delay(30000);
```