# Puppeteer - Extract only the results that contain a certain text

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, puppeteer

How can I extract / export only the urls that contain the `reddit.com` domain?

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
const fs = require('fs').promises;

let browser;
(async () => {
  browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    headless: true,
    args: ['--no-sandbox']
  });
  const [page] = await browser.pages();

  await page.goto('https://old.reddit.com/', {
    "waitUntil": "networkidle0"
  });
  const aElems = await page.$$('a.title');
  const urls = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < aElems.length && i < 10; i++) {
    const href = await aElems[i].evaluate(e => e.href);
    const newPage = await browser.newPage();
    await newPage.goto(href, {waitUntil: "networkidle0"});

    const url = await newPage.evaluate(() => document.location.href);
    console.log(url);
    urls.push(url);
  }

  await fs.writeFiexportle('export.json', JSON.stringify(urls));
})()
  .catch(err => console.error(err))
  .finally(() => browser?.close())
;
```

Thank you!

I tried this:

```
const href = await aElems[i].evaluate(e => e.href.includes('reddit.com') );
```

but it didn't work :(

Comment: I found this solution [https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734052/2151960](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62734052/2151960)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [if URL contains function in puppeteer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62725357/if-url-contains-function-in-puppeteer)